# lower case to Uppercase function - C

Tags: c, function

I've written this function to convert a lowercase str that is preset into it's uppercase variant. I've tried every different configuration I know that converts lower case to uppercase, however when I print it. It still ends up in lower case. So I am a tad Stuck.

```
char* stoupper(char str[]);

char str[100]= "uppercase";

printf("%s" , stoupper(str)); // Test to make sure it is working 

char* stoupper(char str[])
{ 
      int i = 0; 

      while(str[i] != '\0') 
      { 
                   if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') 
                   str[i] = str[i] + ('A' - 'a'); 
                   i++; 
      }
      return str;
}  

/* I've tried various variations of this function this is just the one i had first */
```

Comment: You will want to make a new string inside of that function to return.

Comment: Your code only modifies already-uppercase letters.

Comment: @squiguy, why do you say that?  Conversion in-place seems like reasonable semantics to me.

Comment: And your code also ignores the fact that not all platforms have sequential bytes representing chars `'A'..'Z'`. Is there some reason `str[i] = toupper(str[i])`, using [`toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) from ctype.h isn't considered?

Comment: There's also a pretty nice [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) function in `ctype.h`

Comment: @CarlNorum I guess it would just be a little clearer.  Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: You're trying variations because you don't understand what you're doing.  First understand how to work out if something is lower case and then you need to understand the ascii chart on how to do the transform.

Answer (score 3):

Your code only modifies already-uppercase letters, and turns them into who-knows-what (well, I'm sure you could figure out with an ASCII table).  If you want to operate on lowercase letters, you need to change your `if` condition:

```
if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
```

Answer (score 2):

why are you reinventing the wheel? ctype.h is your friend

Use the toupper(int) method. Something like

```
char* stoupper(char str[]);

char str[100]= "uppercase";

printf("%s" , stoupper(str)); // Test to make sure it is working 

char* stoupper(char str[])
{ 
      int i = 0; 

      while(str[i]) 
      { 
          str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
          i++; 
      }
      return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your if condition should be:

```
if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
```

Comment: They are just as trivial as each other.

Comment: yes, islower() would be more portable, in case a-z are not represented by sequential values.

Answer (score 0):

your condition in if statement needs to be changed

> if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')

May I suggest another way to change Uppercase to lowercase and vice-versa

```
char* stoupper(char str[])
{ 
      for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
          if(!(str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z')){
              str[i]=str[i]^' ';
          }

      return str;
}
```

this method works because

[ASCII value of a lowercase character] XOR [ASCII value of ' '] =[ASCII value of that same character in UPPERCASE ]